# Hyphens or underscores when referencing a path alias in Drupal 7 templates?

Tags: 7, theming

I have a hyphenated path alias in my site and I need to reference it in a template hook, but it seems hyphens get converted to underscores in templates, so I'm wondering how I would go about outputting the code correctly.

My function is something along the lines of if my path alias is "change-directory" then use the "page__change-directory" template. So my question is, would it be "change-directory" or "change_directory" in my template?

Answer (score 2):

When a hyphen is used in a template filename, or template suggestion, the hyphen is replaced with an underscore. That is done in [theme_get_suggestions()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_get_suggestions/7), and [drupal_find_theme_templates()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/drupal_find_theme_templates/7) which use, respectively, the following code.

```
// Remove slashes or null per SA-CORE-2009-003 and change - (hyphen) to _
// (underscore).
//
// When we discover templates in @see drupal_find_theme_templates,
// hyphens (-) are converted to underscores (_) before the theme hook
// is registered. We do this because the hyphens used for delimiters
// in hook suggestions cannot be used in the function names of the
// associated preprocess functions. Any page templates designed to be used
// on paths that contain a hyphen are also registered with these hyphens
// converted to underscores so here we must convert any hyphens in path
// arguments to underscores here before fetching theme hook suggestions
// to ensure the templates are appropriately recognized.
$arg = str_replace(array("/", "\\", "\0", '-'), array('', '', '', '_'), $arg);
```

```
// Transform - in filenames to _ to match function naming scheme
// for the purposes of searching.
$hook = strtr($template, '-', '_');
if (isset($cache[$hook])) {
  $implementations[$hook] = array(
    'template' => $template, 
    'path' => dirname($file->uri),
  );
}
```

Whenever you are adding a theme template suggestion, or you are looking for a template file to use, you should replace hyphens with underscores, in the same way Drupal does.